# Add four blocks with mini border lines

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my code. I have created a main-header block with white background and I would like to add four blocks that come to next to each other in the same line, I want to add a big font text in the center, a small font text below the big font text and also I want to add the mini border lines like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d27Zc.png

Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
  background-color: #edf1f5;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #edf1f5;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main-row {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* position: relative; */
    /* min-height: 1px; */
    /* padding-right: 15px; */
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    /* margin-right: -38px; */
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 93%;
    height: 60px;
    /* display: table; */
    content: " ";
}

.middle-row {
    width: 20%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.middle-number {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.lower-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}




</style>
<body>

<div class="main-row">
    <div class="middle-row">
        <span class="middle-number">0</span><br>
        <span class="lower-text">Opened</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
        <span class="middle-number">0</span><br>
        <span class="lower-text">Click Rate</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
        <span class="middle-number">0</span><br>
        <span class="lower-text">Subscribers</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
        <span class="middle-number">0</span><br>
        <span class="lower-text">UnSubscribers</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I try it, I can create the width from the left to the right and I can also create the height, but I have got no idea how I can add the four blocks that come next to each other in the same line. And also I have got no idea how I could add the mini border line for each block as you can see the small grey lines in the picture.

Can you please show me an example how I can add four blocks that come to each other in the same line, a big and small texts on the top and bottom and add a mini border line for each block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with 4 blocks:

```css
body {
  background-color: #edf1f5;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main-row {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 93%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.middle-row {
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.middle-row:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-row">
    <div class="middle-row">
      <p>11</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
      <p>22</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
      <p>33</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-row">
      <p>44</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also here is a link to a flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does as this is what I am looking for so thank you very much for this. Problem are now resolved. :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you.